# updating state and attribute values using plugin

Tags: crm

I am trying to update both the state and value of an attribute for an entity by writing plugin for CRM 2013. I did try to set the state of an activity using setStateRequest but I am not sure if we can update attribute value as well. I've registered the plugin on Merge message to change the state of an activity. How can I update an attribute value along with state change? Here is my code so far for state ch

```html
 protected void ExecutePreCaseMerge(LocalPluginContext localContext)
        {
            if (localContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
            }

            // TODO: Implement your custom Plug-in business logic.

            IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
            IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

            //The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("SubordinateId") &&
                context.InputParameters["SubordinateId"] is Guid)
            {
                try
                {
                    Guid subordinateId = (Guid)context.InputParameters["SubordinateId"];

                    var fetch = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                                  <entity name='task'>
                                    <attribute name='new_issuephase' />
                                    <filter type='and'>
                                      <filter type='and'>
                                        <condition attribute='regardingobjectid' operator='eq' uitype='incident' value='" + subordinateId + @"' />
                                        <condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />
                                      </filter>
                                    </filter>
                                  </entity>
                                </fetch>";

                    EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));
                  

                    if (ec.Entities.Count > 0)
                    {
                       
                        // Create an ExecuteMultipleRequest object.
                        ExecuteMultipleRequest requestWithResults = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
                        {
                            // Assign settings that define execution behavior: continue on error, return responses. 
                            Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                            {
                                ContinueOnError = false,
                                ReturnResponses = true
                            },
                            // Create an empty organization request collection.
                            Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
                        };

                        foreach (var item in ec.Entities)
                        {

                            SetStateRequest setStateRequest = new SetStateRequest();
                            setStateRequest.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("task", item.Id);
                            setStateRequest.State = new OptionSetValue(2);
                            setStateRequest.Status = new OptionSetValue(6);

                            requestWithResults.Requests.Add(setStateRequest);

                        }

                        ExecuteMultipleResponse responseWithResults =
                            (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(requestWithResults);
                    }
                }
```

ange.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You must do the update as a separate request but you can execute it together with the SetStateRequests inside the same ExecuteMultipleRequest:

```
foreach (var item in ec.Entities)
{

    SetStateRequest setStateRequest = new SetStateRequest();
    setStateRequest.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("task", item.Id);
    setStateRequest.State = new OptionSetValue(2);
    setStateRequest.Status = new OptionSetValue(6);

    requestWithResults.Requests.Add(setStateRequest);

    //New Code
    item.Attributes["attributetobeupdated"] = "Updated Value";
    UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest() { Target = item };
    requestWithResults.Requests.Add(request);

}

ExecuteMultipleResponse responseWithResults =
    (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(requestWithResults);
```

Note that if any of the requests fail the ExecuteMultipleRequest will not throw an error but will return the details of the individual failures within the ExecuteMultipleResponse.  It seems that a common reason for this operation failing is that by default SQL server queries are configured to time out after 30 seconds.  More info here:

http://manyrootsofallevilrants.blogspot.in/2012/09/ms-crm-2011-timeout-settings-and-limits.html

Comment: After testing this out I experienced the same issue where the ExecuteMultipleRequest fired but nothing happened.  This is because when there are errors in individual requests the MultipleRequest does not fail but instead returns these errors within the ExecuteMultipleResponse (there is a similar situation happening here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/144172.aspx).  In my case I was getting a SQL timeout and needed to update a registry key: http://manyrootsofallevilrants.blogspot.in/2012/09/ms-crm-2011-timeout-settings-and-limits.html